# Multiple conditions inside single 'if' in SML

Tags: sml

How can multiple conditions be specified under single if? For example, consider the following java code snippet:

```
if(a==1 && a>b){
    //statements ;
}
```

How can above code be written in sml? I know that I can achieve the goal by using two if's but still if there is a method to specify in the way I want, then it will be smooth.

Comment: Warning: there is no == in SML. There is a == in OCaml that you should not use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SML's equivalent of `&&` is `andalso`. For `||` there is `orelse`:

```ml
if a = 1 andalso a > b
then (* ... *)
else (* ... *)
```

Comment: @lonut G. Stan Do we always need to add 'else'?

Comment: @AnkitShubham SML's philosophy is strongly against overloading. `and` is used for defining mutually recursive functions hence not available for use as a logical operator. `andalso` was chosen by the developers instead. My guess is that it was felt to be too stylistically jarring to have `andalso` paired simply with `or`, so `orelse` what chosen instead, even though `or` by itself isn't used for anything.